# How to cap frame rate (or GPU usage) in Just Cause 2 PC?

Tags: pc, performance, just-cause-2

I play Just Cause 2 PC on my Radeon 4850 (single slot) and no matter how I tweak the graphic settings (from lowest to highest), Afterburner utility keeps telling me that JC2 is using ~99% GPU utilization.

At that level, R4850 temp could hit easily 100C, cranking the fan to maximum speed.

R4850 clock rate is 500/750 when idle and 625/993 when under load. Afterburner lets me cap with 500/750 under load but JC2 hogs the GPU nonetheless.

Can anyone suggest a way to cap my GPU in terms of GPU usage or frame rate?

BTW, I plan to buy a replacement in AMD's Southern Islands (R7XXX series) once it is out.

Comment: other than the noise why do you want to limit the performance?

Comment: I suspect JC2 hogs maximum GPU resources to churn out insane frame rate. Anyone remembered the bug in StarCraft 2 menu screen causing unlimited frame rates?

Comment: I try to set all my games to have a 30fps cap just because of the noise of my GPU, it bothers me more than the lower frame rate. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to the game's command line parameters: `/frameratecap=n` where n is the frame rate.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tried it and it works. I even played it with /frameratecap=10 just for kicks. I would like to reward you with a up vote. Q @Moderators: Can a poster reward working answers with up vote, or only by fellow peers who can confirm the answer themselves?

Comment: You can **upvote any helpful answer**, and it's good practice to **accept** (click the check mark) next to the answer you found **most helpful** and/or directly solved your problem.

Comment: How do you access these command line parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Force VSync on in the Catalyst Control Center, this should cap your frame rate to the refresh rate of your monitor (probably 60 or 75) which will reduce utilisation of your GPU.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. Played it just now with AfterBurner reporting 75fps with VSync on and 80+ when off.